# Ungroup column R and assign binary variable for each unique entry

Tags: r, group

I have following dataframe [df] in R:

| Flair | Text | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YOLO | asder | 10:01 |
| Fluff | qetrtgf | 10:02 |
| Fluff | eqargrstgfh | 10:04 |
| Fluff | qrettzuh | 10:05 |
| Fluff | erghgfxbhs | 10:17 |
| Art and Media | qaerzgh wtruws | 10:27 |
| Charity | eztzutzui | 10:31 |
| Memes | etzuj | 10:54 |
| Question | rehbgfd | 10:55 |
| Provocative | hetzjas | 10:56 |
| ... | ... | ... |

which i like to transform to this:

| Text | Time | Flair_YOLO | Flair_Fluff | Flair_Art | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asder | 10:01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| qetrtgf | 10:02 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| eqargrstgfh | 10:04 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| qrettzuh | 10:05 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| erghgfxbhs | 10:17 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| qaerzgh wtruws | 10:27 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| eztzutzui | 10:31 |  |  |  |  |
| etzuj | 10:54 |  |  |  |  |
| rehbgfd | 10:55 |  |  |  |  |
| hetzjas | 10:56 |  |  |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |

As the problem is hard to describe i was looking into ungroup() but was unable to find the correct formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reshaping problem from long to wide format. But, since you are asking some additional arrangements I did not consider this as a duplicate.

Firstly, we can create an additional column with ones for 'value' requirement in reshaping by,

```
df$Flair_ <- 1
```

Than by using the `reshape` function from `BaseR` we can get the result.

```
out <- reshape(df, idvar = c("Text","Time"), 
        timevar ="Flair",sep = "",
        direction = "wide")
out[is.na(out)] <- 0 # changing NA columns to 0
out
```

gives,

```
#             Text  Time Flair_YOLO Flair_Fluff Flair_Art and Media ...
#1           asder 10:01          1           0                   0
#2         qetrtgf 10:02          0           1                   0
#3     eqargrstgfh 10:04          0           1                   0
#4        qrettzuh 10:05          0           1                   0
#5      erghgfxbhs 10:17          0           1                   0
#6  qaerzgh wtruws 10:27          0           0                   1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
Flair,Text,Time
YOLO,asder,10:01
Fluff,qetrtgf,10:02
Fluff,eqargrstgfh,10:04
Fluff,qrettzuh,10:05
Fluff,erghgfxbhs,10:17
Art and Media,qaerzgh wtruws,10:27
Charity,eztzutzui,10:31
Memes,etzuj,10:54
Question,rehbgfd,10:55
Provocative,hetzjas,10:56",sep=",",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```